# How are multiple minus operators evaluated?

Tags: c

```
int main( void )
{

    int a, b,c ;
    a = -3 - - 3 ;
    b = -3 - - ( - 3 ) ;
    c= -3 - - - -3;

    printf ( "a = %d b = %d c=%d", a, b ,c) ;
}
```

This was the question and to find the answer I simply ran the program and found the result

> a=0   b=-6     c=0

But I am not supposed to use computer while answering these set of questions  . So that is a problem  : is it that no matter how ,any '-' signs are there compiler would get it  correct ? There is a pair  of braces for 'b' but not for 'c' and clearly that made no difference . Would anyone please explain ?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is about the order of evalution and operator precedence. You can answer your own question with these two links:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: The key to understanding this is to realize that C has two different `-` operators. The unary one and the binary one. As it happens in this case though, C will give you the very same result as plain elementary math.

Answer (score 7):

Each unary `-` negates the expression that comes before it, and binds right to left.  Also, it has higher precedence that the binary `-` operator which binds left to right.  So this:

```
c= -3 - - - -3;
```

Is the same as:

```
c= (-3) - (- (- (-3)));
```

And yes, the results of these expressions are well defined.

If on the other hand you were dealing with the preincrement or postincrement operators `--` or `++`, and attempted to use them on the same variable more than once in the same expression, that's when you run into [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: For completeness: `c= (-(3)) - (- (- (-(3))));`  Another `()` around 3's.  The `-`  is not part of the integer constant `3`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the sign change

```
a = -3 - -3 = -3 + 3 = 0
b = -3 - - (- 3) = -3 - (+3) = -3 - 3 = -6
c = -3 - - - -3 = -3 - - 3 = -3 + 3 = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

`-3 - - ... - - 3` is read as negative three minus negative ... negative negative 3.